# C# inheritance re-casting

Tags: c#

Let's assume you have a list of type animal and you add objects of type cat and dog to it.
Both cat and dogs inherit from animal and each have their own specific fields.

Do they lose those fields if you get the objects back from that list and re-cast them from Animal back into their original type of cat or dog?

Comment: `get the objects back from that list and re-cast them back into what they were at the start`.... did you try that before asking this question?

Comment: You don't lose anything no.

Comment: Rep-farmer bait. Do some work, people!

Answer (score 0):

No.

The objects that you store are still objects of type cat or dog, they are just being temporarily treated as the broader type "animal". If you got them out and successfully cast them to the correct type then they you would be able to see all the data that they have always had.

Answer (score 0):

No. The object themselves are always of the same type; they don't change types halfway through their lifetime. They might be treated as another type in a certain context (like in a list), but that doesn't change what they are.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **no**, they certainly do not lose their public member access.

Here is a working implementation of your example:

```
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal> ();
            var dog = new Dog ();
            dog.BallsFetched = 5;
            var cat = new Cat ();
            cat.MiceCaught = 23;
            animals.Add(dog);
            animals.Add (cat);

            Console.WriteLine(((Cat)animals [0]).MiceCaught);
        }
    }

    public class Animal{
        public string Color;
        public string Name;
    }

    public class Cat : Animal{
        public int MiceCaught;
    }

    public class Dog : Animal{
        public int BallsFetched;
    }
```

You could also use the [**is** operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) to check if an object belongs to a certain declaration before casting it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically when *casting* to another type you *convert* that object.

```
double d = 123.456;
int i = (int)d; // d value is gone forever
double dd = (double)i; // you loose .456 part
```

However, in case of casting to *base class* (or interface) conversion in fact doesn't occurs. Think about casting in that case like if you are only able to see (through window? ;)) only those members, what new type defines (new type = base class). When it's cast back, you remove that window and see complete object again.

In this example

```
public class A {}
public class B : A { public object B}
public class C : B { public object C; }

var c = new C() { B = 1,  C = 2 };
```

You can cast `c` to

```
var a = (A)c; // through A window - nothing is visible

var b = (B)a;
var test1 = b.B;  // you can see something through B window, test1 = 1

var cc = (C)b;
var test2 = cc.C; // you can see everything again, test2 = 2
```

While there is a casting to **change type**, object is the still the same. Nothing gets lost.